# Is there a method to clear Expo cache?

Tags: react-native, redux, expo

I'm working on a task where I have to update a product images. Expo cache is posing a problem, when I update the product images and re-render the screen it does update my store state but doesn't show it. When I manually cleared expo cache it did work.

I have also tried using the 'Cache-Control' header, but that didn't solve the problem.

Is there a method I can call to clear expo cache ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know the only way to clear Expo's cache is to add the `-c` flag to your `expo start` command.

Here's their [page](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/introduction/already-used-react-native/#useful-commands) on useful commands:

> - expo start -c --localhost --ios
>
>   - start expo server, clear cache, load only on localhost and open on iOS simulator

I don't think there's a method in their SDK that clears the cache while the app is running like you want to.

Comment: Thank you, but that's not what i'm asking for. I need to call a method which clears the cache after editing the product. I couldn't find one in Expo's documentation.

Comment: AFAIK there's no way to clear the cache after the app is running.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete the cache you can use [FileSystem](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem/#managing-giphys) from Expo. In that example you can delete the directory in the cache using FileSystem.deleteAsync

```
// Deletes whole giphy directory with all its content
export async function deleteAllGifs() {
  console.log('Deleting all GIF files...');
  await FileSystem.deleteAsync(gifDir);
}
```